# Run function on all template renders?

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to run a function after any template is rendered? Sometimes I need to run a snippet of jQuery on all templates, like a snippet that creates Bootstrap tooltips, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
_.each( Template, function( template, name ) {
  if ( name !== "__define__" ) {
    template.rendered = function() {
      // ...
    };
  }
});
```

If you're using the template engine preview (run meteor with `meteor --release template-engine-preview-5.5`) you don't need the if statement. Then again, if you're using the new template system, you shouldn't have to run jQuery code on every template re-render in the first place.